# Snowflake Stream Consumption

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a question on stream consumption.

As per my setup I have a parent table telemetry_data which is constantly updated by app analytics data. I create a stream on top of the parent table telemetry_data_stream to read new records added to the parent table. To consume the stream, I execute a Create Table as statement which consumes the stream and resets it to accept new changes after the consumption.

For example, If the SQL statement took 3 seconds to be executed, what happens to the data that was added to the parent table during this 3 seconds. Would the data reflect in the new table I create based on the stream using `create table as SELECT * FROM catalog_returns_stream;` or would it be contained in the stream as a part of the new version. Is there a chance of dataloss due to the time taken during stream consumption? If so, is there a way we can be sure we wont face such a situation?

More of it I would like to understand how does the stream manage consumption and reading of new data while both of them happening at the same time. Does the stream advance to the point when the  transaction started on it or when it ended?

I tried to constantly add data to the parent table while also consuming the stream. The time for the sql is quick enough hard to tell if there is any data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream is a living object.  It does not store any data and hence the word reset is not really applicable.  When you are consuming data your are basically updating the offset.

You can read more about it https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro.html#offset-storage

`create table as SELECT * FROM catalog_returns_stream;`  may not be the best way to consume a frequently updating stream.

Kindly also note that each table can have multiple streams on it at the same time.

A table that is being updated while the stream on it is being consumed is a very common scenario.  The stream (offset) then points to the 'first' row which was not consumed during the last read operation.

Hope that helps